# Uploading file using PHP CURL - file missing

Tags: php, curl, upload

I'm testing the possibilite to upload a file using cURL.
The versions of the servers are PHP 5.4

To upload from the 'send' server I'm using this code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="Filedata" id="Filedata" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {


  $real_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array('name' => 'test.txt', 'file' => '@'.$real_name);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.site1.com/upload_remote.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

  curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I see the the $data array using print_r($data) and everything seems ok.

In the 'remote' server (address: http://www.site1.com/upload_remote.php ) I have this code:

```
$file = 'test2.txt'

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {

        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";

  }
```

But the file is not there
There is no error at the error_logs file.
Am I forgetting anything?
Thank you.

Comment: See here: http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

Comment: I've tryed the code but not successful

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the move_uploaded_file is the path of destination where file should be moved and you are just passing $file which is not directory.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: I've changed the destination to:   $file = '/';  (same directory), even though the file is not there...

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error? Can you please add else to the if statement to check if move_uploaded_file is returning true or false.

Comment: Is returning false and my error_log file is blank also

Comment: I found other way. Thank you